# Mail client: Public key pinning

Tags: server

I'm running my own mail server setup:
- IMAP: Dovecot
- SMTP: Postfix

There are 4 clients which retrieve emails via IMAP:
- iOS (Default client: Apple Mail)
- Android (Default client)
- Mac (Default client: Apple Mail)
- Windows (Thunderbird)

The problem: I don't want these mail clients to trust **anybody** except my server's certificate. (MITM risk w/ compromised CA)
Is there a way to "untrust" all certificates, which were shipped by default (only for SMTP/IMAP)?

Also is there something like HPKP (HTTP-Public-Key-Pinning) for IMAP?
My domain and Mail Clients don't "support" DNSSEC, that's why I can't use DANE.

It seems that only Thunderbird has an add-on ("Certificate Patrol") which allows what I want. However this is useless, as my other three mail clients don't have a similar add-on.
It's enough if an attacker is able to MITM's one Mail Client to get my password..

Maybe I should switch to something like *-Challenge-Response instead of plain password authentication?

Comment: +1 mail clients are notorious for talking to ANY certificate, even self signed, without carping.  Where mail client-server is usually a one-to-one relationship, pinning should be easier than it is.

Answer (score 2):

**No dice**
I don't think you'll find a way to pin the mail server cert across *all* these clients. Not unless you cripple the devices' cert stores down to *only* your own CA's cert. And that would work. But it would also mean that regular HTTPS would stop working.

**VPN instead?**
Could you put your mail server behind a VPN instead? This should be easier to nail down to just a specify cert on the clients.